# Do i need Promise.promisifyAll() in every module file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

If i need fs in multiple files with Promise (Bluebird), should i call every time Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs')) ?
Or would it be better with a small module with

```
module.exports = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'))
```

and only import that module?

If i get it right, my first choice will every time promisfy the fs module and the second will only link to the same module, which is only one time promisfyed. Or will be my first choice doing the same like my second?

EDIT:
I tested the two options with:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird') 

let time1start = Date.now() 
for(let i = 0; i <= 1000;i++){ 
    let fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs')) 
} 
console.log('Time gone 1 Test: ' + (Date.now() - time1start)) 

let time2start = Date.now() 
for(let i = 0; i <= 1000;i++){ 
    let fs = require('./testInc') 
} 
console.log('Time gone 2 Test: ' + (Date.now() - time2start))
```

testinc.js:

```
module.exports = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('fs'))
```

The results are:
Time gone 1 Test: 891 
Time gone 2 Test: 10

So my theory is right and the second is faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first solution, a promisify version of fs will be generated every time you need it. But in your second solution, the promisify will happens only once, when the module is loaded into memory, then every time you used it, you will just pointing to the same object.

```
// file fs-promise.js
module.exports = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));



// other file
const fsp = require('./fs-promise.js');
```

Both solutions will work, I think you should evaluate the performance of using one or the other.

Comment: I have tried with `const Promise = require('bluebird')

let time1start = Date.now()
for(let i = 0; i <= 1000;i++){
    let fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'))
}
console.log('Time gone 1 Test: ' + (Date.now() - time1start))

let time2start = Date.now()
for(let i = 0; i <= 1000;i++){
    let fs = require('./testInc')
}
console.log('Time gone 2 Test: ' + (Date.now() - time2start))`

testinc.js:
`module.exports = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('fs'))`

Time gone 1 Test: 891
Time gone 2 Test: 10

So the second is faster. Thanks for your help ;)